# Bind class if a dynamic variable is true [all in v-for]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

Sorry for my code but I'm new with Vue.

I have 5 span items like this
[span with :class]

```
              <span class="bars">
                <span class="bar" :class="{ selected1: isActive[0] }"></span>
                <span class="bar" :class="{ selected2: isActive[1] }"></span>
                <span class="bar" :class="{ selected3: isActive[2] }"></span>
                <span class="bar" :class="{ selected4: isActive[3] }"></span>
                <span class="bar" :class="{ selected5: isActive[4] }"></span>
              </span>
```

These match to 5 grey circles. The classes 'selected1, selected, ...' fill the circles with 5 different colors. 
"isActive" is an array of 5 boolean variables [false, false, false, false, false].
To change the statement of these boolean variables I use a function that fires every time I get data from Firebase.

```
  data() {
    return {
      isActive: [], // boolean array
      ricettario: [] // array of firebase data
    };
  },
```

So when isActive[0] is true the span becomes filled, when isActive[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIiOK.png) is true the span becomes filled, etc...

The function I use is named "setDiff" which picks the data from Firebase Database and puts it to a switch statement.

```
// Firebase get data
created() {
    db.collection("ricettarioFirebase")
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          let ricetta = doc.data();
          ricetta.data = dayjs(ricetta.data) // time
            .locale("it") // time
            .format("D MMMM YYYY"); // time
            this.setDiff(ricetta.diff); // diff = "molto facile || facile || ..."
          this.ricettario.push(ricetta); // push data to ricettario[]
        });
      });
  }


// Function that change isActive[]
  methods: {
    setDiff(diff) {
      switch (diff) {
        case "molto facile":
          i = 1;
          for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            this.isActive[j] = true; // only one filled span
          }
          break;
        case "facile":
          i = 2;
          for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            this.isActive[j] = true; // 2 filled span
          }
          break;
        case "medio":
          i = 3;
          for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            this.isActive[j] = true; // 3 filled span
          }
          break;
        case "difficile":
          i = 4;
          for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            this.isActive[j] = true; // 4 filled span
          }
          break;
        case "molto difficile":
          i = 5;
          for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            this.isActive[j] = true; // 5 filled span
          }
          break;
      }
    }
  }
```

The problem is that the DOM receives only the last statement, so every card created with v-for has the same span color. I would like to have the card with different filled span.
The following image shows the problem.
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIiOK.png)

Comment: each selected1, selected2, .. is different color?

Comment: Your for loop is very repetetive, I would put it at the end of the method. So your `switch` statement only sets the value of `i`. Also, I would reset the values of `isActive` to false before you set some of them to true. Use `console.log` to check if the value of `i` is actually what it should be at the end of the method.

Comment: @RobertB. yes!

The problem is gone, thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one global variable `isActive[]`

You are fetching an array of objects from the database.

Then you are calling `setDiff(someString)` for each of the retrieved object. 
Each time you call the function you essentially override the values set by the previous call.

You could make `isActive` a two dimensional array (for example `isActive[item.id][0]`) or attach `isActive` to ricetta before pushing it to ricettario array

```
ricetta.isActive = this.setDiff(ricetta.diff); // remember to return isActive from setDiff function
ricettario.push(ricetta)
```

For this problem you could even use simple CSS and a :class from `ricetta.diff`

https://codepen.io/szkuwa/pen/JjdNYov

Comment: Thank you very much!
I used your "CSS child" technic. In this way, I cut the switch statement and functions.

Everything works correctly :-)